# Find extension of a specific filename

Tags: php, flash, file, mod-rewrite

I am creating a image hosting service and I want to shorten the name so that it has no extension and the files are in the 'root' directory of my server. I've gotten to the point where I can load any PNG file and it will show the image, but say, the file is swf or jpg, it will still try to open the PNG.
Now, here's what I've got currently. If there is an extension on the filename, and the filename ends in gif, jpg, png or swf, it will load the file from the /img/ directory. If not, it will open media.php and parse the file form there
.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/img/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png|swf))$ img/$1 [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ media.php?i=$1 [NC,L]
```

media.php

```
<?php
//Media.PHP
if(!isset($_REQUEST['i'])){
die("No media selected  ");
}
$filename = $_REQUEST['i'];
if(file_exists('img/'.$filename .'.png')){
$header = "image/png";
$ext = ".png";
}
elseif(file_exists('img/'.$filename .'.jpg')){
$header = "image/jpg";
$ext = ".jpg";
}
elseif(file_exists('img/'.$filename.'.jpeg')){
$header = "image/jpg";
$ext = ".jpeg";
}
elseif(file_exists('img/'.$filename .'.gif')){
$header == "image/gif";
$ext = ".gif";
}
elseif(file_exists('img/'.$filename .'.swf')){
$header == "application/x-shockwave-flash";
$ext = ".swf";
}
else die("404 File not found");
header("Content-Type: $header");
@readfile('img/'.$filename."$ext");
```

Now, this works great with images(png,gif,jpg,jpeg) but I cannot get it to work correctly with .swf files. It just downloads them. So, in this case, I can open the file from mydomain.com/MYSWF.swf but not mydomain.com/MYSWF, because it downloads it with the shorter link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There looks to be double equality signs (`==`) for your gif and swf if conditions, while setting `$header`?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this header when it is a swf file:

```
$fileName="filename.swf";
header("Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash",true);
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes",true);
header("Connection: keep-alive",true);
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$fileName");
readfile($fileName);
```